# How to call class method in array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, function, object

```
class MyClass { 
        public function MyMethod() 
        { 
            return 'something';
        }     
        public $perop = array( 'test' => $this->MyMethod() );
    }
```

I have a class MyClass and have a function MyMethod. I want to call MyMethod() under array key as shown above code.

Comment: Obviously you can't do it when defining `$perop`.

Comment: Ok. What problem you are facing then?

Comment: Did you simply try to run the code to find if it would work?

Comment: **FATAL ERROR** Constant expression contains invalid operations on line ...

Comment: Yes I have run this code but, it shows me error - Constant expression contains invalid operations

Comment: Can someone help me to find the solution for this. is there any way to call function into array key.

Comment: @PravinChukkala When do you want to execute the method?

Comment: You could move that assignment into the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

NO.

But this would work and achieve what I THINK you are trying to do

```
class MyClass { 

    public $perop;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->perop = [ 'test' => $this->MyMethod() ];  
    }

    public function MyMethod() 
    { 
        return 'something';
    } 
} 

$tst = new MyClass;

print_r($tst);
```

RESULT

```
MyClass Object
(
    [perop] => Array
        (
            [test] => something
        )

)
```

Comment: Ok, got it. it worked for me. Thanks